# Detaching only the last child in parent using JSPlumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I am working on a project where we have objects in a 4-by-X grid. We are using JS Plumb to connect these objects, but we noticed when it connects `object 4` to `object 5`, that the line makes an ugle diagnoal and ends up crossing behind the first row. Is there a way we can scope the `Draw();` function to only first 4 objects? That way the 5th will still drop to a new line, but won't have the diagonal connectors.

**Here is my JS Function**

In my function, I use a class of `no-lines` on my object's parent element to define a group that will not get the `drawLines();` function at all. I believe since I am drawing these based on the parent function, that I won't be able to stop the draw event for the `last-child` of my parent.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var drawLines = function(){
            $('.training-directory-methodology-stage-classes').not('.no-lines').each(function(){

                var newplumb = jsPlumb.getInstance();

                $(this).find('.training-directory-methodology-stage-class').each(function(index, value){
                    current_class = $(this);

                    if(index>0) {
                        newplumb.connect({
                            source: previous_class,
                            target: current_class,
                            anchor: "Center",
                            connector: "Straight",
                            endpoint: "Blank",
                            paintStyle:{lineWidth:6, strokeStyle:'#4A5C68' }

                        });
                    };

                    previous_class = current_class;

                });
            });
        };

        jsPlumb.ready(function() {
            drawLines();
        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
            $('._jsPlumb_connector').remove();
            drawLines();
        });
});
```

**Here are some of the functions that I've tried**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jsPlumb.detachAllConnections('#jsPlumb_5_20');
    jsPlumb.removeAllEndpoints('#jsPlumb_5_20');
    jsPlumb.detach('#jsPlumb_5_20');
});
```

I also tried to detach based on my parent-container, but to no avail.

```
jsPlumb.detach('convert-container:last-child');
```

Since these projects tend to be pretty code-heavy, I created **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/091pwnaq/)** here were you can see what I have so far!  I appreciate all the help with this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out a solution.

Since we have multiple 'sections' with a different amount of objects in each parent, I decided to build out a separate draw function. This one lets me choose where my lines start and stop in the drawing.

So here is my new 'draw' aka `breakLines();` function.

```
var breakLines = function(){
    // Check this class for the class of '.no-lines'
    $('.training-directory-methodology-stage-classes').filter('.no-lines').each(function(){
      jsPlumb.Defaults.Endpoint = "Blank";
      var endpointOptions = { isSource: true, isTarget: true };
      //Use the iterative divs to find the first and fourth child
      var convert1 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint( $('.convert1'), { anchor: "Center" }, endpointOptions );
      var convert4 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint( $('.convert4'), { anchor: "Center" }, endpointOptions );

      // New Connection
      jsPlumb.connect({
        source: convert1,
        target: convert4,
        anchor: "Center",
        connector: "Straight",
        endpoint: "Blank",
        paintStyle:{ lineWidth:6, strokeStyle:'#4A5C68' }
      }); 
    });
  };
```

To get the added `1-4` on my dynamic divs, I used this function so they would be generated and then have the class added.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".convert-container").each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass("convert" + (i+1));
  });
 });
```

**Note, the divs are not dynamic in my fiddle, but on my live page they are :)

After fitting this function in with my exisiting JS, I was able to turn off the original `drawLines();` function on the sections that had more than 4 objects, and replace it with this. You can see how the new `breakLines();` function pipes my objects in this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/091pwnaq/10/)**